# How to Intercept REST endpoint to receive all headers?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

My current code is

```
@Path("login")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginResource {

    @GET
    @SecurityChecked
    public Response getUser(@HeaderParam("AUTH") @Nonnull final String authToken) {
        return Response.ok("authenticated successfully.").build();
    }
}
```

and `@SecurityChecked` is custom annotation as

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SecurityChecked {

}
```

and Interceptor class as

```
@Interceptor
@SecurityChecked
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SecurityCheckInterceptor");

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object validateUser(final InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

        final Object[] params = context.getParameters();

        LOGGER.info("Authentication token: " + Arrays.toString(params));
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

When I run it I see

```
 Authentication token: [1a629d035831feadOO4uFReLyEW8aTmrCS]
```

**Problem?**
- In my resource class I had to pass the `@HeaderParam` parameter
- How can I read all the `HTTP` headers coming from client?

**Ideal?**
- If the `getUser()` does not take any `@HeaderParam` input and
- Interceptor should be able to give you all the `HTTP` Headers

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to inject [HttpHeaders](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) into your `Interceptor`? (via `@Context private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this by modifying the interceptor I have, the following is code

**Annotation**

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SecurityChecked {

}
```

**Resource Class**

```
public class SecureResource {

    @GET
    @SecurityChecked
    public Response getUser() {
        return Response.ok("authenticated successfully!").build();
    }
}
```

**Interceptor class**

```
@Interceptor
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityChecked
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor, AcceptedByMethod {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityCheckInterceptor.class);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(final HttpRequest request, final ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        final List<String> authToken = request.getHttpHeaders().getRequestHeader("X-AUTH");

        if (authToken == null || !isValidToken(authToken.get(0))) {
            final ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse();
            serverResponse.setStatus(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode());
            return serverResponse;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isValidToken(@Nonnull final String authToken) {
        LOGGER.info("validating token: " + authToken);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Class declaring, final Method method) {
        // return declaring.isAnnotationPresent(SecurityChecked.class); // if annotation on class
        return method.isAnnotationPresent(SecurityChecked.class);
    }
}
```

and then I run my Integration tests by deploying the resource class in JBoss and issuing following commands on command-line

```
curl --header 'X-AUTH: 1a629d035831feadOOO4uFReLyEW8aTmrCS' http://localhost:8080/market-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/login
curl --header 'InvalidHeader: InvalidHeaderValue' http://localhost:8080/market-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/login
```